# Html.ActionLink and its binding

Tags: asp.net, html.actionlink

How ASP.NET MVC understand what action method exactly it should use in Html.ActionLink("text","myAction")? Why I dont need to use the name of controller? Also, I know, another version of this method exists (with controller as parameter). What is action binded to?

Answer (score 0):

MVC knows the current controller. More precisely, the MVC core stores route data in the `RouteData` object:

```
var controller = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
```

Comment: and if I want to use not the current controller i should use another version of this method, right?

Comment: You should specify the new controller's name in `ActionLink`, right.